# Keeping the Space Between Characters Constant Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, timer

What I want to do is keep the numbers in my timer still.

At the moment, some of the characters are slightly bigger than others, so when my timer counts rapidly they move rapidly, making it hard to read.

> **Example**
>
> "0" might be 5px wide
>   "." might be 1px wide
>   "7" might be 6px wide
>   Therefore, "0.7" would be 12px wide.
>
> But if "6" is 5px wide, that would mean "0.6" is 11px wide, and this is what I believe is causing the movement when the timer increases rapidly.

I've found a example of what I want my characters to do [here](https://www.csgocrash.com/play/1). As you can see the timer stays still, and the numbers increment without pushing the other characters.

I'm writing a similar website but using a canvas to encase the timer. I've tried using spacing but that doesn't work. I'm working in Javascript, which links to a HTML Page.

Any information would be appreciated.

Comment: The easiest way is just to use a [monospaced font](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monospaced_font)

Comment: Wow that was quick, and yes this is exactly what i was looking for. Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you really need to use a specific font with varying width letters, you could write something which evenly spaces the characters. However, the much simpler way is to use a [monospaced font](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monospaced_font), such as [Courier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Courier_(typeface)).

[image: proportional vs monospaced]

A CSS rule which does what you need might look something like this:

```
.timer
{
    font-family: "Courier New", Courier, monospace;
}
```

This would tell the browser to use Courier New if there is an exact match for it on the user's computer. If they don't, it would use any other Courier font they have. Failing that, it would use any monospace font they do have.

Comment: this seams like the best answer for me, since I don't have to worry about centering any text. Thank you again Michael

Comment: Sidenote, I'm also using https://fonts.google.com to find and import my custom fonts,

Comment: Cool. That's a great way to ensure a consistent user experience.

Answer (score 1):

The quickest way would be to use a monospaced font.
[Here](https://www.typewolf.com/top-10-monospaced-fonts) are some popular ones.

If you don't want to use a monospaced font you could wrap each character in a `<span>`, and have the spans all the same width.

```css
.clock span{
  display: inline-block;
  width: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="clock">
  <span>1</span>
  <span>1</span>
  <span>:</span>
  <span>1</span>
  <span>1</span>
</div>

<div class="clock">
  <span>2</span>
  <span>8</span>
  <span>:</span>
  <span>5</span>
  <span>8</span>
</div>
```

Comment: thank you for the help however this wouldn't apply to me as my numbers are randomly generated then displayed via ctx EXAMPLE BELOW                     

 ctx.font = "150px PT Mono monospace";
 ctx.fillStyle = "Black";
 ctx.textAlign = "center";